# How to get Google Street View / Virtual Tour to display as sphere in mobile web browsers?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view, google-maps-embed

Is it possible to get Google street view/google business view virtual tours to display as a sphere instead of a flat image ( or equirectangular I believe is the correct name) using the google maps api or embed? So far in my trials I have not been able to get it to display correctly. It just displays as a flat image (equirectangular) when on a mobile device.

The tour I have shown below is this one (just a random one I found): https://www.tourmake.it/nl/tour/e2f74fe593a99a3db61e921b417afbee

Ones that I have found that work on iOS/Andriod (Note these are complex google made ones so I am assuming they have done some custom coding to make it work?):
- https://insideabbeyroad.withgoogle.com/en/all-access/studio-1/1060#x=&y=&z= 
- https://nightwalk.withgoogle.com/en/panorama/218

**iOS - Safari (Just displays flat image)**

[image]

**Android - Google Chrome ( Works 100% how I want)**

[image]

Another note regarding this demo above. It works fine on Andriod Google chrome but not iOS Google Chrome...

Any tips on how to get this looking good on both iOS and Android browsers?

Comment: Would the [Street View Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) suffice? I haven't used it yet personally but it seems to be the perfect case for your scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I had to add `google.maps.streetViewViewer = 'photosphere';` before initializing the object. That uses the new beta streetview renderer.